# ldap_add in php returning "already exists 68" error

Tags: php, ldap

I just cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong, I've scoured the web for answers but cannot find anything that works. Please can someone look at my code and tell me where I'm going wrong? If I comment out "objectclass" I get "server is unwilling to perform 53", if I change the OU to something silly (the $dn) then I get "Naming Violation", if I mash the keyboard and put in random letters for the user's name I still get "already exists" error even though no parts of the things I'm entering exist. If I add an ldap_mod_replace line in for another CN in the same OU it works fine so I know the connection is working. I've tried without the '[0]' on all except objectclass too (as I've seen in all examples). Company and user info edited obviously.

```
$server = "ldap://ServerName.domain.co.uk";
$dn = "OU=Advertising,OU=EmailDepartmentAccounts,OU=Administration,OU=Central,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk";

//domain user to connect to LDAP
$user = "helpdesk.ldap@domain.co.uk";
//user password
$psw = "Password";

$ds = ldap_connect($server);
if ($ds) {
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    $r = ldap_bind($ds, $user, $psw);

    $proxyaddresses_array = array();
    $proxyaddresses_array[0] = "X400:c=GB;a= ;p=Company Name p;o=PWEXCHANGE;s=Kitbag;g=Digital;";
    $proxyaddresses_array[1] = "SMTP:test.maff@domain.co.uk";
    $proxyaddresses_array[2] = "smtp:test.maff@other.co.uk";

    //$NewUser = array();
    $NewUser["cn"][0] = "Test Maff1";
    $NewUser["userprincipalname"][0] = "Test.Maff1@domain.co.uk";
    $NewUser["samaccountname"][0] = "Test.Maff";
    $NewUser["objectClass"][0] = "top";
    $NewUser["objectClass"][1] = "person";
    $NewUser["objectClass"][2] = "organizationalPerson";
    $NewUser["objectClass"][3] = "user";
    //$NewUser["givenname"][0] = "Test";
    //$NewUser["sn"][0] = "Maff";
    //$NewUser["instancetype"][0] = 4;
    //$NewUser["physicaldeliveryofficename"][0] = "Leeds";
    //$NewUser["displayname"][0] = "Test Maff";
    //$NewUser["proxyaddresses"] = $proxyaddresses_array;
    //$NewUser["department"][0] = "IT";
    //$NewUser["company"][0] = "Company Name";
    //$NewUser["homemta"][0] = "CN=Microsoft MTA,CN=STH-EXC-01B,CN=Servers,CN=BSP,CN=Administrative Groups,CN=Johnston Press plc,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk";
    //$NewUser["displaynameprintable"][0] = "Test Maff";
    //$NewUser["mailnickname"][0] = "Test.Maff";
    //$NewUser["useraccountcontrol"][0] = "512";
    //$NewUser["primarygroupid"][0] = "513";
    //$NewUser["name"] [0]= "Test Maff";
    $NewUser["objectcategory"][0] = "CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk";
    //$NewUser["mail"] = "Test.Maff@domain.co.uk";

    if ($NewUserAdded = ldap_add($ds, $dn, $NewUser)) {
        echo "success<br />";
    } else {
        echo ldap_error($ds) . " " . ldap_errno($ds);
    }
    ldap_close($ds);
} else {
    echo "unable to connect to LDAP server";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might be wrong, but from what I read in your code you have an entry `OU=Advertising,OU=EmailDepartmentAccounts,OU=Administration,OU=Central,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk`. And as far as I interpret your code you want to add an entry **below** that entry. But you have to provide the DN of the **new** entry as second parameter to `ldap_add`. But you provide the **baseDN** of the new entry. and that is already there. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to add something into it.

So you should call something like the following **before** calling the `ldap_add`:

`$dn = 'cn=' . $NewUser['cn'][0] . ',' . $dn;`

That uses the baseDN and prepends it with the cn of the current user.

Hope that helps

Comment: This is still valuable in '19. Was banging my head for a few days and this- $dn = 'cn=' . $NewUser['cn'][0] . ',' . $dn; also did the trick for me.