# ldap_add(): Server is unwilling to perform - Using PHP to insert records into AD

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm using ldap_add to insert records into Active Directory, but I'm getting **Warning: ldap_add(): Add: Server is unwilling to perform** on the line for ldap_add in my PHP file.

The strange thing is that I'm able to perform an **ldap_search** using "cn=some name" filter on the same directory, but it fails when I use ldap_add.

I read a lot of StackOverflow questions on the same issue and most of them have trying with an MD5 hashed password and/or using TLS_REQCERT never in ldap.conf file, and I have tried both, but without any success.

Here is my code after ldap_connect and ldap_bind, upto which everything works fine-

(For connection I'm using- ldap_connect("ldaps://MyIP:636"))

```
if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";

        //This part works fine and I'm able to do ldap_search with cn filter on the same directory
        $searchResult = ldap_search($ldapconn,'OU=Users,OU=Testing OU,DC=My,DC=Domain,DC=Net', "(cn=manish test)") or die ("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));
        $data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);

        echo '<h1>Dump all data</h1><pre>';
        print_r($data);
        echo '</pre>';
        //ldap_search ends

        //ldap_add part begins
        $data['cn'] = 'mk test02';
        $data['sn'] = 'test02';
        $data["objectclass"][0] = "top";
        $data["objectclass"][1] = "person";
        $data['givenName'] = 'mkss';
        $data['displayName'] = 'mk test02';
        $data['name'] = 'mk test02';
        $data['sAMAccountName'] = 'mk_test02';
        $data['userPrincipalName'] = 'mk_test02@SomeName.Net';
        $data['mail'] = 'manish.k@domain.com';
        $data['userPassword'] = "{MD5}".base64_encode(pack("H*",md5('Password1!')));
        //Also tried using just- $data['userPassword'] = md5('Password1!');

        $adInsert = ldap_add($ldapconn, "OU=Users,OU=Testing OU,DC=My,DC=Domain,DC=Net", $data);
        echo 'error- '.ldap_error($ldapconn);

        if (!$adInsert)
        {
            echo '<p>AD Insert failed</p>';
            exit;
        }
    }
```

I get **Warning: ldap_add(): Add: Server is unwilling to perform** and **AD Insert failed**(from  my own error message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone looking for an answer for this- Go through the useful suggestions by **@GabrielLuci** in the other Answer.
What worked for me was a combination of those suggestions and the Top Answer on this post-
[ldap_add in php returning "already exists 68" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645547/ldap-add-in-php-returning-already-exists-68-error), specifically this part-

```
So you should call something like the following before calling the ldap_add:
$dn = 'cn=' . $NewUser['cn'][0] . ',' . $dn;
```

So right above the line where I called **ldap_add**, I changed that to the following-

```
$dn = 'OU=Users,OU=Testing OU,DC=My,DC=Domain,DC=Net';
$dn = 'cn=' . $data['cn'] . ',' . $dn;
$adInsert = ldap_add($ldapconn, $dn, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a couple problems:

First, this:

```
$data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);
```

But then you are also using the `$data` variable for all the information for the new account. All the data returned from `ldap_get_entries` is getting sent as part of the information for the new account. That will very likely make it not work.

I also suspect that the way you are setting `objectClass` *might* be a problem. However, I have never created an account in PHP, so I'm not sure. I would have guessed that this would work:

```
$data["objectclass"] = "user";
```

But I could be wrong. Maybe your way is just fine.

Also, the password: The [`userPassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/f3adda9f-89e1-4340-a3f2-1f0a6249f1f8) attribute only works when certain settings are enabled. Even when it is, it's really just a synonym for the real password attribute, [`unicodePwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2). So `userPassword` *might* work, but `unicodePwd` will *always* work.

The password string must be in a very specific format, which that documentation describes. Specifically, surrounded in quotes and in UTF-16 encoding. You seem to be trying to compute the MD5 hash of the string. I think that's the real reason you are getting that error.

The PHP documentation for [`ldap-modify-batch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-modify-batch.php) has an example for changing a user's password, but shows a function that converts a regular string into the format that AD expects:

```php
function adifyPw($pw)
{
    return iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE", '"' . $pw . '"');
}
```

In your case, you can use it like this:

```php
$data['unicodePwd'] = adifyPw('Password1!');
```

Keep in mind to that you must be connected securely (that usually means LDAPS) to be able to set or change any passwords.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had already tried this out during my testing (using unicodePwd in place of userPassword & using UTF-16 encoding), but it still errors out on the 'ldap_add' line, with 'server is unwilling to perform' message.

Comment: Well the password is definitely one issue. I took another look at your code and I updated the beginning of my answer with a couple other things that might be causing problems.

Comment: I'm sry I'm commenting out the search part in my final code. I had included it just to show that the search is working fine. The $data['cn'] is the first instance where $data is used.      Any other reason you can think of why the search would work but not the add? (I have double checked my access rights and I have the correct write access as well)

Comment: You can try using `print_r($data)` before `ldap_add` again just to make sure it looks good. Also, there is the `objectClass` attribute like I added to my answer too.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I posted what finally worked for me as an Answer.

Comment: That makes sense. I missed that in the documentation for `ldap_add`.